# What are the differences of store(n.) and storage(n.)?

Tags: meaning, differences, word-usage, nouns

Store ex: The store's inventory has to be entered manually into the database.

Storage ex: Storage closet is where you will find all our office supplies.

Comment: Hello 107. You need to add a few more examples for each (and preferably simpler more central usages). The store shuts at 9. Our food store has been raided by mice. // The storage of gunpowder obviously presents problems. It is in cold storage.

Comment: Also, please add in what you found in your dictionary search and what's unclear about those definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In American usage, "store" is a place where goods are kept for sale.
Ex.: Walmarts is a discount store.
In British use, "store" can be a place where supplies are kept for future use, in other words, for "storage."
Ex: As it was summer, she decided to put her fur coat in storage.

Comment: I'm a native speaker of American English and "food store" sounds perfectly natural to me as a place where food is stored or a place where you can by food, depending on context.  Is it really a BrE thing to use "store" as a place where supplies are kept?